# добавление обработчика движений мыши Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Необходимо добавить обработчик движения мыши, пытаюсь реализовать это через анонимный класс, но что-то идет не так, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
package fun;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

class FrameFun extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton but1 = new JButton("YES!");
    private JButton but2 = new JButton("NO!");


    private void initLabel () {
        label = new JLabel("Do you ready work for eat?");
        panel.add(label);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(label.CENTER );
        label.setBounds(150,10,200,50);
    }
    private void setPanelOnTheFrame() {
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,200));
        panel.setLayout(null);
    }
    private void setButtonsOnThePanel() {
        panel.add(but1);
        panel.add(but2);
        but1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 30); 
        but2.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 30); 
    }
    public void initFrame() {
        setPanelOnTheFrame();
        setButtonsOnThePanel();
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Fun");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        initLabel();
    }
    but2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                but2.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 30);
          }
    });

}
```

В главном классе просто создается объект класса FrameFun и вызывается метод initFrame()

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример обработки:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

    class FrameFun extends JFrame {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    JWindow window = new JWindow();
                    JLabel label = new JLabel();
                    window.add(label);
                    window.setSize(100, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                            label.setText(String.format("x:%s y:%s", e.getX(), e.getY()));
                            window.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen() + 10, e.getYOnScreen() + 10);
                            window.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setSize(500, 500);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

На Вашем примере:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

    class FrameFun extends JFrame {
        private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        private JLabel label;
        private JButton but1 = new JButton("YES!");
        private JButton but2 = new JButton("NO!");


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            FrameFun frameFun = new FrameFun();
            frameFun.initFrame();
        }

        private void initLabel() {
            label = new JLabel("Do you ready work for eat?");
            panel.add(label);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(label.CENTER);
            label.setBounds(150, 10, 200, 50);
        }

        private void setPanelOnTheFrame() {
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            panel.setLayout(null);
        }

        private void setButtonsOnThePanel() {
            panel.add(but1);
            panel.add(but2);
            but1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 30);
            but2.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 30);
        }

        public void initFrame() {
            setPanelOnTheFrame();
            setButtonsOnThePanel();
            add(panel);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Fun");
            setResizable(false);
            setVisible(true);
            initLabel();

            panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    but2.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 100, 30);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```